# How to formulate a nested model when the higher-level variable is continuous?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, continuous-data

I am trying to design a model that will allow me to simultaneously assess the effects of local and landscape-scale variables (both quantitative and continuous) on an ecological response (in this case, bee abundance).

Normally, I would do this quite simply: bee abundance ~ local variable + landscape variable.

However, my local-scale data come from 3 different locations in each landscape. Thus, for every 1 landscape variable value, I have 3 local variable values. If I follow the simple model outlined above, the landscape-scale variable will be pseudoreplicated.

I considered incorporating a random factor for landscape identity into the model, but I think this would make it difficult/impossible to assess the effects of the (continuous) landscape variable of interest, given that each "random" landscape has its own unique, quantitative landscape variable value.

I have done some searching online on this topic, but all the sources I have found seem to link back to mixed models, where (as I understand it) the higher-level variable is discrete/categorical rather than continuous/quantitative.

Is there some kind of nested/multilevel/hierarchical/etc. model that I can use to simultaneously assess the effects of my local and landscape variables, given that I have 3 local variable values for each landscape variable value?

General statistical guidance would be wonderful; names of R packages that I can use would also be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not use one-hot encoding (dummy encoding) for this? http://psychstat3.missouristate.edu/Documents/MultiBook3/Mlt07.htm

Comment: @Nishad No, because my variables are continuous, not categorical.